# How to update to the "new choice API" in Symfony 2.7

Tags: forms, symfony

I have just started to work on an existing Symfony 2.7 project which should now be prepared to be updated to Symfony 2.8.

Now I came across the following [information from the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage) of the `ChoiceType`:

> The **choices_as_values** must be set to true in all cases. This activates the **"new" choice type API**, which was introduced in Symfony 2.7. If you omit this option (or set it to false), you'll activate the old API, which is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. To read about the old API, read an older version of the docs.

When checking the `'choice'` form fields within the project, I noticed, that none of them uses the `'choices_as_values' => true`. I assume that this was simply skiped when the project was updated from Symfony 2.6 to 2.7 some time ago.

Thus it seems, that currently all `'choice'` form fields are still using the "old" API. To be up to date and prepared for Symfony 3, I would like to change this.

**What exactly do I have to do?**

When comparing the `ChoiceType` docs of Symfony [2.6](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/choice.html) and [2.7](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html) one can see that:

- ...the `choice_list` is deprecated in 2.7
- ...2.7 has several new options like `choice_loader`, `choice_name`, etc

Since `choice_list` is not used in the project, this change should not have any effect, **should it?**

New options are nice, but if the have not been used yet there should also be no problem after the update, **right?**

The only thing I am concerned about is, that existing options could have changed their behavior.

I recognized that the order of keys and values of the 'choices' options has been switched:

```
// 2.6
'choices'  => array(
    'm' => 'Male',
    'f' => 'Female',
),

// 2.7
'choices'  => array(
    'Male' => m,
    'Female' => f,
),
```

**Is this right?** This would be pretty big change. However, when adding the `'choices_as_values' => true` option (== activating the "new" API) and **not** changing the `choices` option, **I do not see any difference in the generated HTML code.**

I compared the 2.6 and 2.7 docu but found no other changes, but not that does not mean that there are no other changes :-)

**So, are there other changes I have to consider?**

Comment: By default the choice keys now are basic array index integer keys. By using `choices_as_values` the values of that array will become the keys. After that you can use `choice_label` and pass a closure to format the label.

Comment: Well, as described I do not see any difference in the generated HTML code, no matter if `'choices_as_values'` is set or not. In both cases the choice is added `<option value="m">Male</option>` to the generated `select` tag. I works without any problem, even though I do not use `choice_label` anywhere.

Comment: Okay then I know what you mean now. The default value <3.0 is `true`, but you should remove it because it is deprecated. See https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values

Comment: This does not make sense. The `choices_as_values` option was introduced in 2.7 and the docs clearly say: "The choices_as_values **must be set to true in all cases**".  `'choices_as_values' => true` will active the new API, `'choices_as_values' => false` or not using `'choices_as_values'` will activate the old API. The old API is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. Thus removing this value does not seem to be the right solution.

Comment: The introduction in 2.7 was necessary because of the refactorization, in order to offer BC it was added so the old behavior could be removed in 3.0. The 2.7 documentation offers more info, but also see: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization

Comment: Thank you, but this still does not answer my question in any way. I know this article, and as described in the question, I know that the ChoiceType has changed. The question is, how to handle the update correctly without adding bugs. The question is, how `'choices_as_values'` works since it seems to have non influence on the created HTML code. The question is there any other changes that I have to keep in mind, in order to handle update properly.

Comment: To focus on a future upgrade to 2.8+, you should change your choices to the 2.7 code snippet you provided and add `choices_as_values => true`. Then you will always be safe, and you are sure you can upgrade. Only 2.7 requires you to explicitly add `choices_as_values => true` if you did not change your choice values yet.

Comment: I am running two copies of the project. Both use identical custom files, classe, etc. But one uses Symfony 2.7 and the other 2.8. In both versions I cannot see any difference between the `ChoiceTypes`. In both versions it does **not** make any difference if `choices_as_values => true` is used or not. However there should be difference, since both the 2.7 and 2.8 docs explicitly say so (see the quote in my question). So which difference exactly does `choices_as_values => true` make? Why can't see any difference? Is there no difference or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no difference between 2.7 and 2.8, but between 2.6 and 2.7 where the array keys still were used as values. I had the same problem while upgrading to 2.7, but took the gamble and everything was okay because as you already state the html is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124551/discussion-between-andrei-herford-and-rvanlaak).